# Binary search tree node removal crashing program?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, binary-search-tree

I need to write the code for my own BST. All the functions work accept I don't understand why I'm having trouble deleting a node.

Here is my first version of inserting a new node:

```
void insert(const T& arg)
{
    if (!root)//tree is empty, as to not dereference prev at end
    {
        root = new PbstNode<T>(arg);//constructor sets both left and right to null
        return;
    }

    PbstNode<T>* prev;
    PbstNode<T>* traversal=root;

    while (traversal)
    {
        prev=traversal;//prev is parent only after loop ends

        if (arg < traversal->data)//new data is less than, send left
            traversal = traversal->left;
        else//new data is greater than or equal to, send right
            traversal = traversal->right;
    }

    if (arg < prev->data)
        prev->left = new PbstNode<T>(arg);
    else
        prev->right = new PbstNode<T>(arg);

}//end insert
```

Then I was thinking about how I could do it without keeping track of the predecessor node pointer, because I think if I tried to remove a node by first searching for it like above, I'd have to know if the ptr to the node to be deleted is a left or right node, and it may also be the root.

So then I tried writing an insert function where I could get the 'real' ptr to the insertion node position, without having to use `prev->left` or `prev->right`.

```
void insert(const T& arg)
{
    PbstNode<T>** insertPtrPtr= &root;//

    PbstNode<T>* aPtr;

    while (aPtr= *insertPtrPtr)
    {
        if (arg < aPtr->data)//new data is less than, send left
            insertPtrPtr = & aPtr->left;
        else//new data is greater than or equal to, send right
            insertPtrPtr = & aPtr->right;//insertPtrPtr = & (*insertPtrPtr)->right;
    }
    //i cant use aPtr here
    *insertPtrPtr = new PbstNode<T>(arg);//constructor sets both left and right to nullptr
}//end insert
```

The above works after testing inserting various values and searching for them.

However, then I tried writing the remove function in a similar way:

```
void remove(const T& arg)//
{
    PbstNode<T>** delPtrPtr= &root;

    PbstNode<T>* aPtr;

    while (aPtr= *delPtrPtr)
    {
        if (arg == aPtr->data)
        {
            //fixTree
            delete (*delPtrPtr);//makes program crash?? had to be created with new
            return;
        }
        else if (arg < aPtr->data)
        {
            delPtrPtr = & aPtr->left;
        }
        else
        {
            delPtrPtr = & aPtr->right;//delPtrPtr = & (*delPtrPtr)->right;
        }
    }
    std::cout<<"Requested removal not found in tree.\n";
}//end remove
```

The line `delete *delPtrPtr` crashes the program, but the variable pointed by `*delPtrPtr` had to be created with `new`, right? What's going on?

Any reply is appreciated.

Comment: 1) Are you sure that `*delPtrPtr` isn't null? 2) Why do you use that extra indirection (i.e. why use `delPtrPtr=&...` and `*delPtrPtr` instead of `delPtr=...` and `delPtr')? 3) Why do you have two pointers that seem to be doing the work of one?

Comment: To add to this, once you delete the object, you need to set the the pointer to NULL. Otherwise, your tree still points to the free'd memory.

Comment: @Beta 1) if `*delPtrPtr` were null, that would not cause that crash.  2 and 3) The indirect pointer is needed so you can do the step bagel_lord forgot and Nick Cano mentioned `*delPtrPtr=0;`.  When you need an indirect pointer, it is convenient (though not necessary) to also give a name to the direct pointer, so you can `aPtr->data` instead of `(*delPtrPtr)->data` and `delete aPtr;` instead of `delete *delPtrPtr;`  but you still can't `aPtr=0;` instead of `*delPtrPtr=0;`

Comment: @bagel_lord, before you fix the bug bagel_lord mentioned, I expect it crashes because you allocated with `new` but then deleted it twice.  After you fix that bug, if the function is still broken, edit your post to show that correction, so that obvious bug doesn't distract from finding any others.

Comment: That's not how BST node removal works, regardless of technical details. What if your node has children? You are going to lose them.